# Android Google Map API error with onMapLoadedCallback

Tags: android

when I add the callback for onMapLoaded I get an error

Here is my class:

```
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.casinos_karte);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (map == null) {
        Toast.makeText(
                Casinos_Karte.this,
                "Can't load map",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.finish();
        return;
    }
    map.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new OnMapLoadedCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Here is Error:

```
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862): Process: de.wolfsline.db.info, PID: 23862
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.wolfsline.db.info.casinos.Casinos_Karte
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at de.wolfsline.db.info.casinos.Casinos_Auswahl$1.onClick(Casinos_Auswahl.java:65)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-05 19:40:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have class not found exception  check your library.